# How to show a single validation message for the whole JSF form?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, validation

I have a JSF form  with number of fields. PrimeFaces normally does validation in this way:
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/pprAjaxValidations.jsf

But I have more than 30 fields in my JSF form, so if I did this validation, it does not look good. How can I provide only a single message like "Please fill missing values" for any field if it is missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your could render the message conditionally based on [`FacesContext#isValidationFailed()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#isValidationFailed%28%29).

```
<h:outputText value="Please fill out missing values" rendered="#{facesContext.validationFailed}" />
```

Note that this would only make sense if you have **only** the `required="true"` validation enabled and you thus don't use any converters or other more specific validators for which the enduser would of course like to see a more specific message.

Comment: I was just about to suggest the same, with the exception of checking `facesContext.maximumSeverity.ordinal gt 0` instead. I guess the difference is that yours will only show on validation errors, while mine shows also on other errors?

Comment: @BalusC... With the above approach in the backend `required=true` will be shown as unhandled messages right?Is there anyway to get rid of them?